# home page from site installed in subfolder

Tags: php, web, deployment, content-management-system, prestashop

I am using a CMS (PrestaShop) installed in a subfolder of root (shop-1)

`domainName/shop-1` points to index of PrestaShop.

`domaineName/shop-2` points to a custom page under PrestaShop.

My problem is: I want the main domain page `domainName/` to also point to a second custom page in PrestaShop. The goal is to manage the 3 pages with the same CMS.

Is this achievable via htaccess? What do you think could be the solution?

PS: I know it can be done via multistore but I think it is overengineering.

**Edit:**

[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) is the main site where there is an old PrestaShop.

- I want to move this site to:

> [www.domain.com/shop-1](http://www.domain.com/shop-1)

which means all PS built-in urls will be at `/shop1/*`

- I also want another future `shop-2` at

> ```
> www.domain.com/shop-2
> ```

But for the moment I only need a landing page for shop-2, that’s why I thought about a CMS page or module front controller(under same PS installation).

- Now how can I make the root url [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) to point to a url that can be also managed by PrestaShop engine?

In other words I want to have one PS installation to manage all urls:

1. /shop1/* for the pages of old site.
2. /shop-2 is just a front controller page or CMS.
3. `/`  landing page of whole website, also a
   front controller page hopefully.

Thanks a lot dear

Comment: What I understood:
domain.name --> Custom page 1
domain.name/shop-2 --> Custom page 2
domain.name/shop-1 --> Prestashop homepage
Am I correct? 

What do you mean by custom page ? a CMS page from PrestaShop or a `.html` file you created?

Comment: @AnthonyRave, exactly. And I mean by custom page a custom front controller in a module. Thanks a lot

Comment: The goal is to be able to have the 3 pages under same theme (tpls, scss, js...)

Comment: Ok! You can try to go under Shop parameters > Traffic & SEO. Here you can define what URL you want to bind with each front controller including index I believe.

Comment: What about other pages other than index of shop-1. In fact, I already have old website that I need to be under /shop-1/*. The physical location of PS is under root. Please more help.

Comment: @AnthonyRave, could you please just agree with me that it is not built in in PrestaShop?

Comment: You may have to configure your server aswell. But I feel like I didn't understand well what you are trying to do... Can you attach a schema of your wanted architecture?

Comment: @AnthonyRave I appreciate your time, thanks a lot. I couldn't draw a picture but I have added an edit in where I explained my situation better. Again, thanks

Comment: Tank you for the details. I understand it way better. Unfortunately I won't be able to help you since I didn't do something equivalent.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /landing-page/
    
    # Handle requests to the landing page
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?fc=module&module=mycustommodule&controller=landingpage [QSA,L]

Answer (score 1):

To redirect the main domain page to a custom page in **PrestaShop**, you can use the **[RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)** directive in your website `.htaccess`
like

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /shop-2 [L]
```

This tells the server to redirect the root URL to the custom page located at `/shop-2`.
Make sure that you have **[mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)** **enabled** on your server for this to work